# Replace Select Box Options With JSON Result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box, and when I click on a button, an ajax request is made, and it returns json object the object contains a new list of options for the select box. Is there any way that I can remove all the options from the select box and replace them with the new list?

```
<select id="cat-0" >
    <option value="0">Select One...</option>
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes of course there is. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Lets see the format of that JSON data!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `.html()` to insert new options clearing the existing ones.

```
$('#cat-0').html(newOptions);
```

But of course you need to construct options from your JSON Data something like this.

```
var json=[{value:'1', text:'Option1'},
     {value:'2', text:'Option2'},
     {value:'3', text:'Option3'}];

 var options=$('<select/>');
    $.each(json, function(id, ob){
      options.append($('<option>',    
                      {value:ob.value,
                        text:ob.text}));
    });

 $('#cat-0').html(options.html());
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b49Px/)

Comment: Rather than appending it to DOM in each iteration, i recommend updating it at once especially when you have so many options to be created.

Answer (score 3):

```
//Clear the select list    
$('#cat-0').empty();

//then fill it with data from json post
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {   
     $('#cat-0')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",key)
         .text(value));
    }
```

Comment: value is an object with this method